# LIKE or match by beginning for binary strings in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, index, blob, varbinary, bytea

I need to match a binary column with its beginning.

For text columns it's easy: `LIKE 'image/%'`. This uses BTREE index if any.

Is it possible to do this also using an index for a binary column?

BTW, I store UTF-8 encoded strings in Binary, because there is no hard standard that all of them are UTF-8. So, I store a binary representation (maybe even with \0 (zero) bytes), as I cannot use UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

**It appears `LIKE` just works fine against `bytea` in PostgreSQL:**

```
create table t(v bytea primary key);
insert into t(v) values
(E'\x12\x31'),
(E'\x12\x34\x56\x78'),
(E'\x12\x35'),
(E'\x12\x34'),
(E'\x12\x38');
```

Then:

```
select *
from t
where v like E'\x12\x34%'
```

gives you:

| v |
| --- |
| \x12345678 |
| \x1234 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ae53c517dc56ba727f95c0ddeb6967f9)

Check the `EXPLAIN` plan to see the index is using prefix matching.

---

**You can also use simple half-open interval logic: `>= AND <`**

For example:

```
select *
from t
order by v;
```

returns:

| v |
| --- |
| \x1231 |
| \x1234 |
| \x12345678 |
| \x1235 |
| \x1238 |

which shows you how the ordering goes.

You can do:

```
select *
from t
where v >= E'\x12\x34' and v < E'\x12\x35'
```

which gives

| v |
| --- |
| \x12345678 |
| \x1234 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6923b8136e2c76612613276d8e20ad00)

Note that this only works with whole bytes. For half bytes, you need to add a `0` to fill out the byte.

---

The same thing is possible [in SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b0152ab1005578c968f091b8b17de81f).